# Any tool to convert SQLite database to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, migration

[DBConvert](http://dbconvert.com/convert-sqlite-to-mssql-pro.php?DB=10) is one such tool I know. Any open source or any other product?

Comment: Can't get dbconvert to access named instances on SQL Server 2008...

Answer (score 6):

You could try the [SQLite Manager for Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)

It's got the ability to export your SQLite db to a .sql file which you could then run in SQL Server. Might not be perfect, but it is free.

Comment: To launch, press alt > tools > SQLite Manager

Comment: this worked nicely up until the lastest update of firefox (57.0)...  the add-on is currently dead as of 11-24-2017...  it actually happened while i was converting a database...  that's why i landed on this page...

Answer (score 4):

For me it was n't that much complicated to convert in notepad++ by replacing:

number -> int

text -> [varchar] (1000)

GUID -> UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Bool -> bit

autoincrement -> IDENTITY (1,1)

long -> int

double -> float

create table Delivery (
 Id INT not null,
 primary key (Id)
}

->

create table Delivery (
 Id INT not null primary key clustered,
-- primary key (Id)
}

and at the end I checked constraints, pk, column type and size in a SQL diagram.

Answer (score -2):

For anyone looking for an answer to this question now, there is a free windows tool that can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB) that allows you to convert an SQLite database to an SQL Server database.

Comment: Good shout, though sadly that only works from MS SQL to SQLite; not the other way round.

Answer (score -2):

Try this -- worked great for me and after 30 days its only $100 :-)

http://www.razorsql.com/index.html